# Popup as User Control or Templated Control Windows 8 / WinRT C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I would like a way to create a popup control in one place such as a user control. Then across multiple views, I can use the same popup control.

I think the solution could be to use either User Control or Templated Control. I have never used either of them.

Can I use either the User Control or Templated Control for a popup?

Is there a better solution?

I should also mention that I am using C# / XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant apply a Control template directly to a Popup control so a user control is exactly what you need for this.

Just create a User control containing all the content and UI you want and then reuse that control inside a new popup control in every view you want it to appear.

Comment: This is a fine solution. Thank-you BenBtg. I was originally looking for a way to create the complete popup control in a single place. Since the popup control itself only has one or two properties set, what I really wanted was something for the content of the popup.